# Align 2 almost identical photos to be in the same position and proportions

Tags: image-manipulation

I have 2 photos of the same building from different years (100 years difference). I want to align the new photo to match the dimensions and position of the old photo so both photos will look the same if placed one over the other. Any app or software i can do this with?

Idealy I would like to load the old photo as a fix photo and then on top load the new photo and play with its size and alignmeht until i will reach sync.

Thank you Yuval

Comment: You might be able to get Hugin to do some sort of aligned mapping.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing the pictures similar but not perfectly aligned, ie not the same lens / camera combination and not the exact same camera position? They will need aligning and warping then outputting as separate images. I've never tried this myself, but [Hugin](http://hugin.sourceforge.net/) should be able to do this with a bit of messing about. It's actually an open-source GUI for a [package of tools](http://wiki.panotools.org/Main_Page) to create panoramas, focus stacks and image blends and is highly adaptable. This also makes it a little tough to get into at first but the web pages have plenty of [tutorials](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0ahUKEwiKuOyw7sXWAhWrLsAKHQ3oAMMQjBAIMjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fhugin.sourceforge.net%2Ftutorials%2F&usg=AFQjCNE6LnSLu32N1g9nzEiAjIgtTfattw), and there are many more on the web in general.

As I write this though I can not access any of the hugin web pages, the connection is just timing out. The [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hugin_(software)) gives a nice overview though.

Comment: Thank you both.
Indeed the web page is unavailable for some reason.
Will try to get it elsewhere.

Cheers.

Yuval